# OpenXML spreadsheet comma separated numbers gives content error

Tags: c#, excel, csv, openxml

I am creating an Excel document using OpenXML in a C# webrform project.

In one cell I input an ID, and in some cases multiple IDs separated by commas similar to this:

```
**ID1**         **ID2**
10756409    3090,3093,3130
10776516    3105
10806938    3123
10817453    3090,3093,3100
```

Each cell in both columns are given **CellValues.String** DataType.

When I open the spreadsheet I get the ***"Found a problem with content.  Would you like us to recover..."*** warning.

When I click yes, the data is fine, but the cells with CSV values are left justtified (as opposed to right justified for the non-CSV values) have the green corner and say ***The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe***.

How can I get the Excel to open without the warnings?

Comment: Add `'` before content for the cells you need it to be treated as text.

Comment: I hardcoded this into the SELECT and had the same warnings:

**'''111,111,111' as 'ID2',**

The resulting Excel cells show '111,111,111

Comment: This can be "fixed" by using ', ' (comma + space) or a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the warning message.
You can try the following code using the SAX approach:

```
openXMLWriter.WriteElement(new IgnoredErrors(new IgnoredError()
{
   SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue> 
   { 
      InnerText = "A1:Z100" 
   },
   NumberStoredAsText = true
}));
```

It should create the following xml tag:

```
<ignoredErrors>
  <ignoredError sqref="A1:Z100" numberStoredAsText="1"/>
</ignoredErrors>
```

Adjust the cell range to fit your needs.

Comment: your solution doesn't work for me. Where should I apply this line - I've tried before/after writing cell value, with different ranges and even tried applying to stylesheet. None worked, I'm using SAX approach.